# OpenVPN on ubuntu keeps asking for a CA file

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I'm trying to connect to the OpenVPN by using username and password on a Ubuntu 20. The OpenVPN server is working normally because I can connect it on my Macbook.

But When I try to connect it from the Ubuntu, It asks for a CA file but I only have a username and password to connect.

Here is my **client.conf**,

```
client
dev tun
remote https://xvpn.myserver.io
auth-user-pass auth.txt
```

My **auth.txt**,

```
myusername
mypassword
```

I run the VPN by using this command,

> sudo openvpn client.conf

And here is the error,

> Options error: You must define CA file (--ca) or CA path (--capath)
> Use --help for more information.

Please help.

*edited
I have added (based on https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/#using-username-password-authentication-as-the-only-form-of-client-authentication)

```
client-cert-not-required
username-as-common-name
```

to the client.conf But I got below error,

```
DEPRECATED OPTION: --client-cert-not-required, use --verify-client-cert instead
Options error: --client-cert-not-required and --verify-client-cert require --mode server
Use --help for more information.
```

Comment: Probably relevant: https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/#using-username-password-authentication-as-the-only-form-of-client-authentication

Comment: I added to the client.conf and go another error, 
DEPRECATED OPTION: --client-cert-not-required, use --verify-client-cert instead
Options error: --client-cert-not-required and --verify-client-cert require --mode server
Use --help for more information.

Comment: the worst OpenVPN configuration is the one which doesn't use certificates for security

Answer (score 2):

The CA is not used for user/client verification, but for verifying the server you are connecting to.

You either need to specify the exact CA certificate (using the `--ca` cli parameter, or `ca` option in your config file or embed the certificate in the file), or by specifying a path with trusted ca certificates with `--capath`).

Once the client has verified that it is connecting to a trusted server, it will continue with the auth-user-pass to log in to the server.

So even if you're not using certificates to authenticate yourself, you at least need the CA certificate of the server. You don't need a client certificate and key, just the CA certificate. The VPN server admin will need to provide you with that.

Comment: But what Windows or Macbook does not ask for the CA file ?